# «...если выделят субсидирование, может быть будет ремонт...» Верно ли без запятой после «может быть»?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

«...если выделят субсидирование, может быть будет ремонт...» Верно ли без запятой после «может быть»? Или это вводное?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, неверно. Это действительно *вводное слово* в данном случае:

> *...если выделят субсидирование, может быть, будет ремонт...*

Но если убрать слово *будет, **может быть*** станет членом предложения и запятая будет лишней:

> ...если выделят субсидирование, может быть ремонт...